# Unix macro becomes undefined when compiling with -std=c++0x flag

Tags: c++, gcc

When compiling the code below with **-std=c++0x** flag the **unix** macro becomes undefined and the error "Unix is not defined!" is shown. Is there any reason why this happens and how to fix it? Verified in gcc versions 4.7.2 and 4.8.4.

```
#include <iostream>

#if !defined(unix)
#error Unix is not defined!
#endif

int main()
{
    std::cout << "Hello World!" << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: #include <unistd.h>

Answer (score 10, accepted):

From the GCC manual, [3.7.3 System-specific Predefined Macros](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/System-specific-Predefined-Macros.html):

> The C standard requires that all system-specific macros be part of the *reserved namespace*. All names which begin with two underscores, or an underscore and a capital letter, are reserved for the compiler and library to use as they wish. However, historically system-specific macros have had names with no special prefix; for instance, it is common to find `unix` defined on Unix systems. For all such macros, GCC provides a parallel macro with two underscores added at the beginning and the end. If `unix` is defined, `__unix__` will be defined too. There will never be more than two underscores; the parallel of `_mips` is `__mips__`.
>
> When the `-ansi` option, or any `-std` option that requests strict conformance, is given to the compiler, all the system-specific predefined macros outside the reserved namespace are suppressed. The parallel macros, inside the reserved namespace, remain defined.

Take note of the second paragraph, specifically.

---

**tl;dr**

The `unix` macro is not conforming to the standard, `__unix__` is. When you asked your compiler for `-std=c++0x`, it switched to "strict conformance" where only `__unix__` is available (and the by-default supported "extension" `unix` is dropped).

Answer (score 3):

As others have said 'unix' is a gcc extension to the standard and by specifying `--std=c++0x` you have told it to use the standard. You can instead do `--std=gnu++0x` and it will retain the extensions (Or use `__unix__` as others suggested)

Comment: I usually handle GNU compiler extensions the same way I handle post-1990 *Star Wars*: Existing, but better not mentioned. ;-) On a more serious note, `--std=gnu++0x` does the same for you as using `unix` instead of `__unix__`: Code not compliant with the standard.